# Javascript - measure time to open a tcp connection to a server

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp

I'd like to measure the latency in opening (and closing) a tcp connection to a server.  **I don't want to send/receive any data** since I want as little overhead as possible to eliminate anything on the server side increasing the request time.

Think of it like a TCP ping.  Record current time, connect to host:port, disconnect, calculate delta time.

I believe Javascript doesn't allow opening direct sockets, but I'm hoping given what it can do (e.g. AJAX requests) that it can be used in some shape or form to fit my requirements.

Edit:

Some information about the server:

- It's a remote server, so I'd need to be able to handle the error regarding Same Origin
- It's not a standard webserver, it doesn't support HEAD (this is why I just wanted to open the connection and not send data)
- If I try a GET request, it resets the connection

Even if I could just attempt a connection, and then get a refusal due to the above points, if I can catch the exception I could still use the fact it had connected to determine the latency.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are running inside the application layer, we can only do a latency test over HTTP.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("HEAD", "/", false)
console.time("latency");
xhr.send();
console.timeEnd("latency");
```

**Code description:**

I create an synchronous AJAX request to the current host. I used `"HEAD"` as the method which is very lightweight and does not receive any contents. So, we can assume that the round-trip for a "HEAD" request is very close to actual ping over ICMP or TCP.

For URL, `"/"` (current host) is used. Because of **Same Origin Policy**, you cannot just use any domain like http://google.com unless you are allowed to do so.

I used `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` to measure the duration which is more accurate than using a regular `Date`. However, you can also use `Date` to measure the duration:

```
//...
var now = (new Date()).getTime()
xhr.send();
var duration = (new Date()).getTime() - now; //ms
```

**UPDATE:**
Try this code for measuring the latency even if an exception occurs:

```
try {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("HEAD", "http://google.com" + "/?" + Math.random(), false) 
    console.time("latency");
    xhr.send();
}
catch (e){
    //block exception
}
finally {
    console.timeEnd("latency");
}
```

Please note that I have also added a random number at the end of the URL to prevent browser caching.

Comment: This is almost ideal, unfortunately it's a remote server and doesn't support HEAD (although if I could catch that error, that'd be fine too).  I'll update my post with more information about the server.

Comment: The request/timing capture is working fine, but there doesn't seem to be a way to suppress/catch the 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load..' error due to Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I have tested in Chrome and Firefox and it works regardless of any error. For example I go to msn.com and run the code (which sends request to google.com) in the Developer Tools and it gives me the duration correctly.